# 'perseverare *è*/*è non*/*non è neanche* diabolico ...'

Tags: meaning

a) ... perseverare non è nenche diabolico, ma proprio una pessima idea.

b) ... perseverare è non diabolico, ma proprio una pessima idea.

c) ... perseverare non è diabolico, ma proprio una pessima idea.

i) La seconda parafrasa più aderentemente il noto detto 'perseverare è diabolico, ma quel 'non' dopo la 'è' suona brutto.

ii) La terza è ineccepibile, ma induce a usare un 'neanche' ulteriore come è fatto nella prima.

iii) La prima, volendo significare che una 'pessima idea' è peggio che 'diabolico', non funziona.

Le tre asserzioni di cui sopra (i, ii e iii) sono sensate o, magari, sono prive — tutte o qualcuna — di fondamento logico-grammaticale-linguistico?

> ... perseverare in questo caso è peggio che diabolico, solo una pessima idea.

Inoltre, cari amici, quale delle tre formulazioni (a, b e c) corrisponde meglio alla frase blockquotata qui sopra?

Come scrive @DaG in un commento sopraggiunto "il senso della frase in discussione, a prescindere da come è esattamente formulata, è proprio quello di creare un paradosso, quasi – mutatis mutandis – à la Oscar Wilde (come a dire: la tal cosa non è solo un peccato mortale, e passi, ma addirittura non sta bene con questo abito)".

Comment: Non si capisce  cosa tu voglia dire, penso che la frase sia : *perseverare non è solo diabolico, ma anche una pessima idea.*

Comment: @Josh suggerimento interessante.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer to your question, please consider the option to "accept" it by clicking a checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Buona sera.

Provo ad interpretare quello che dici. Parto dalla frase

> perseverare in questo caso è peggio che diabolico, solo una pessima idea

per me non ha molto senso. Una cosa "diabolica" è una cosa molto brutta, "peggio che diabolica" è ancora più brutta, "una pessima idea" è invece estremamente lieve. Quindi, leggendo la frase precedente per me c'è un controsenso.

Se invece lo scopo è dire che perseverare non è così male da considerarlo diabolico ma comunque un modo sbagliato di agire, la formulerei nella versione c).

La b) è uguale, ma suona male: il non si mette in questo caso davanti all'è perché se viene messo davanti all'aggettivo, ci si aspetta (nel continuo della frase) non un alleggerimento (come è il caso) ma una definizione ancora più pesante, per esempio:

> ... perseverare è non male, è diabolico

sto cioè mettendo l'accento sul primo aggettivo per dare una definizione peggiore di perseverare.

La a) è uguale alla c) solo che inserisci "neanche". Ma in questo caso non serve perché non stai rafforzando una definizione, ma rendendola più leggera.

Spero di essere stato di aiuto.

Comment: «Una cosa "diabolica" è una cosa molto brutta, "peggio che diabolica" è ancora più brutta, "una pessima idea" è invece estremamente lieve.»: Ma credo che il senso della frase in discussione, a prescindere da come è esattamente formulata, sia *proprio* quello di creare un paradosso, quasi – mutatis mutandis – à la Oscar Wilde (come a dire: la tal cosa non è solo un peccato mortale, e passi, ma addirittura non sta bene con questo abito).

Comment: Non era molto chiaro lo scopo della domanda ... ho cercato di rispondere come avevo capito. Se chiarirà, adatterò / cancellerò la mia risposta (anche perché nessuna delle 3 corrispondeva alla frase blackquotata).